# Azure VM NGINX Plus + Web App leads to 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, azure, nginx

I'm working on NGINX Plus setup as a reverse proxy for traffic management and routing on my Azure Cloud Solution.

I'm just getting started and everything works independently, but when I try to use the proxy_pass to route web traffic to a .NET Web App that rests in the cloud, I get 404 errors.

I've tried with an app I've had deployed for a while(a .NET MVC Web App) and also a node express app that is nothing more than the basic offering as a test: 
http://rpsexpressnodetest.azurewebsites.net/

Each of these runs as expected when I go the directly to them, but then when I enable the pass thru I get a 404 error.

I'm using the following config file for nginx:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    upstream web_rps{
        server rpsexpressnodetest.azurewebsites.net;
}

#    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
#    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

#    drop requests with no Host header
#    server{
#       listen 80 default_server;
#       server_name "";
#       return 444;
#    }

server{
    listen *:80;
#       listen *:443 ssl;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web_rps;
    }
}

include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

In any case, if I navigate to http://rpsnginx.cloudapp.net/ (my nginx vm), I always get a 404 web app not found...

> Error 404 - Web app not found.
>
> The web app you have attempted to reach is not available in this
>   Microsoft Azure App Service region. This could be due to one of
>   several reasons:
>
> 1. The web app owner has registered a custom domain to point to the Microsoft Azure App Service, but has not yet configured Azure to
>      recognize it. Click here to read more.
> 2. The web app owner has moved the web app to a different region, but the DNS cache is still directing to the old IP Address that was used
>      in the previous region. Click here to read more.

If I remove the pass through proxy I get the standard "Welcome to NGINX" index.html file, so the NGINX seems to work just fine too...

I sincerely hope my new(b)ness is causing the issue.

Any assistance would be a great help!

Answer (score 2):

First off, big props to NGINX Support for getting back to me as quickly as I could transpose this post from an email I sent them...

More importantly, here is the answer provided by them that worked!

> My guess that this is this the source of the problem.
>   Try adding following directive to "location /" block:

```
proxy_set_header Host rpsexpressnodetest.azurewebsites.net;
```

Worked like a champ!