# why is azure app service responding with 404?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

```
This name.azurewebsites.net page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://name.azurewebsites.net/
HTTP ERROR 404
```

i followed [this](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/deploying-node-js-app-using-azure-devops-part1-74cb13a6bd02) tutorial, everything went smoothly from the build to deployment, i'm using nodejs 10.15.0 and when i hit 
`node -v` in the VM it gives

```
0.10.14
```

**edit**

[image]

Comment: are you passing the right key to Service?

Comment: Are you sure the Azure DevOps deployment process is succeeding?  Have you tried FTPing into the web app to see if the web root has the files you expect?

Comment: just added a pic @BryanLewis

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check to see if adding IIS to pass errors in web.config helps.

```
 <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

In case the above does not help, add the following in the web.config and see if that works.

```
 <staticContent><mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" /></staticContent>
```

In this similar discussion [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549006/azure-vm-nginx-plus-web-app-leads-to-404), another user was able to fix the issue by adding directive to "location /" block:

```
proxy_set_header Host rpsexpressnodetest.azurewebsites.net;
```

You could leverage App Service diagnostics to fetch more pointers on the issue.
To access App Service diagnostics, navigate to your App Service app in the Azure portal. In the left navigation, click on **Diagnose and solve problems**.

Thanks for sharing the screenshot, please do ensure that the site deployment files are available D:\home\site\wwwroot\ directory.

Please check to see if the above works or share more details about your WebApp for further investigation.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if the answer did helped the OP, but `<staticContent><mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" /></staticContent>` is required in order to request static json files.